# How to detect website active routes?

Tags: web-application, web, laravel

I'm building a website using Laravel and I'm just thinking about security.

**I would like to know if there is a way for attacker to detect all active web routes for a website ?**

For example:

```
http://example.com/login
http://example.com/products
http://example.com/products/{id}/items
etc...
```

So, what techniques will attacker use to detect this routes ?

Will he check the website page source and search for links or will he somehow try to detect those links without looking at page source code (brute-force for example).

To be honest, I'm asking because I'm not sure if should put the link to the Content Manager to my homepage or not...

Answer (score 2):

You can using spidering tools, for example:

1. [dirbuster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dirbuster/)
2. [gobuster](https://github.com/OJ/gobuster)
3. [dirb](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dirb/)
4. [nikto](https://github.com/sullo/nikto)
5. [wfuzz](https://github.com/xmendez/wfuzz)
6. [BurpSuite](https://portswigger.net/)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application. They could start with a sitemap like one you provide Google. Or they could crawl it and extract links like a search engine would.

In your case if `{id}` is a sequential number, they might do a simple enumeration attack. Here's a [high profile case](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/freedom-of-information-request-privacy-breach-teen-speaks-out-1.4621970) where that lead to sensitive information disclosure because of poor access control mechanisms.

Last, they could just guess. For example, every web server I run gets attempts to login to the wordpress admin panel. Which is funny for me because I don't run any wordpress sites... not so funny for wordpress users who didn't set a good password.